# Using negation of Uniqueness Quantifier to show a relation is not a function.

Tags: functions, logic, alternative-proof, quantifiers

- $A = \{1,2\}$
- $B = \{2,3\}$
- $R \subseteq A \times B$
- $R = \{(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)\}$

I want to prove $R$ is not a function. That is, I want to show:
$$
\lnot \forall x(x \in A \to \exists y(y \in B \land (x,y) \in R \land \forall z((z \in B \land (x,z) \in R) \to y = z)))
$$

and using logical equivalences I arrive at:
$$
\exists x(x \in A \land \forall y(y \in B \land (x,y) \in R \to \exists z((z \in B \land (x,z) \in R) \land y \neq z))) \tag{1}
$$

---

What I do not understand:
If I find an $x \in A$ such that $(x,y), (x,z) \in R$ and $y \neq z$, isn't it enough to conclude $R$ is not a function ?

I think this would be the symbolization:
$$
\exists x(x \in A \land \exists y(y \in B \land (x,y) \in R \land \exists z((z \in B \land (x,z) \in R) \land y \neq z))) \tag{2}
$$

Perhaps, I am reading in an incorrect manner the Negation of Uniqueness Quantifier. But, I cannot see what would be the difference with my last symbolization and also cannot think a case where my last symbolization fails to represent that $R$ is not a function. I will appreciate any insight.

Comment: Oh, that's very interesting. Thank you, @Olivier Roche. Are you saying the statement you wrote is **stronger** than (1) ? So, (1) is true in more scenarios.

Comment: Sorry about that I don't know what I had in mind. Anyway, it is much simpler to rewrite (1) with the convention that allows to restrict quantifiers, i.e to write $\exists x \in X$, to get the more readable $\exists x \in A \ \exists y, z \in B \  R(x,y) \wedge R(x, z) \wedge y \neq z$..

Comment: No problem. Yes, that convention that allows restricting quantifiers is neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're last statement assumes that $\operatorname{dom}(R) = A$. Yes, establishing that would prove that $R$ isn't a function. The broader statement with the $\forall y$ quantifier allows for the possibility that $\operatorname{dom}(R) \subsetneq A$: if $x\in A$ but $x \notin \operatorname{dom}(R)$, then that $x$ satisfies the statement trivially, as there are no $y\in B$ for which $(x, y)\in R$.